# How to name Lazy Chunk File during build angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have these lazy chunk files during build production. There are many lazy chunk file, why are the name part empty ?

[image: lazy chunk file]

sample of lazy load module defined in routing module

```
  {
    path: 'learning-path',
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/learning-path/learning-path.module').then(m =>m.LearningPathModule) 
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/account/account.module').then(m =>m.AccountModule) 
  },
  {
    path: 'calendar',
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/calendar/calendar.module').then(m =>m.CalendarModule) 
  },
  {
    path: 'coaches',
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/coaches/coaches.module').then(m =>m.CoachesModule) 
  },
  {
    path: 'schedule-calendar',
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/schedule-calendar/schedule-calendar.module').then(m =>m.ScheduleCalendarModule) 
  },
  {
    path: 'schedule-sessions',
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/schedule-session/schedule-session.module').then(m =>m.ScheduleSessionModule) 
  },
```

Comment: Do you have internationalisation set up?

Comment: No. but angular universal

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are not using the flag [namedChunks](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19345) while building or serving your application.

Note that you can directly add the flag to your `angular.json` file or if you have a custom script in your `package.json` file you can simply add it to your settings:

IE:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build-custom": "npm run build --configuration=production --aot=true --named-chunks=true --source-map=true
}
...
```

Comment: With this command I am able to see file name on left column but the Name column is still blank and its same like the name column in screenshot.

Comment: Like most build options, this can be put in angular.json. You can find it in projects/<projectname>/architect/build/options/"namedChunks": true (as @khizer 's answer states)

Answer (score 1):

- Navigate to angular.json file
- Navigate -> projects ->  -> architect -> build -> configuration ->  e.g Production, development, staging -> set `true` for named chunk in order to show named lazy chunk file

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
               ...
              "namedChunks": true,
              ...
            }
          }
        }
```